# Removing listeners in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am writing a simple interactive widget that will eventually end up in an ibook.

It's a game where you drag and drop an item into the correct place, essentially matching animal sounds to the animals that make them.

I add my listeners in the HTML, like this for the target:

```
<div class="target_box_zebra"
     ondrop="drop(event,'zebra')"
     ondragexit="dragLeave(event,'zebra')"
     id="zebra_target"
     ondragenter="drag_enter(event,'zebra')"
     ondragover="allowDrop(event,'zebra_target')"
     ondragleave="drag_leave(event,'zebra')">
</div>
```

Once the correct target has been found (simple `if` statement) I want to remove all the listeners so that it is just an the plane div with its default background image.

I tried unbind but it didn't work. Any suggestions or guidance would be super.

Comment: In this case, don't use inline event handlers, use advanced event handlers: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unbind only works, if you don't use inline handlers.

Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener.

Comment: Thank you. funnily enough this does seem to work,
            document.getElementById(thisTarget).ondragleave =false;
document.getElementById(thisTarget).ondragexit =false;
document.getElementById(thisTarget).ondragenter =false;
document.getElementById(thisTarget).ondrop =false;
document.getElementById(thisTarget).ondragover =false;


which is messy but handy to know when mocking up something fast.  I